# Can we use "draw screen to other apps" to get that app text

Tags: android, android-studio, google-visualization

I want to get the text of the user what he is seeing right now where API will just whole data of that app. but I need only the data user currently seeing.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.

Only accessibility services and other services specifically granted the ability to read the screen content (e.g., Google Assistant-type services) are able to do this.

If any app that could draw over other apps could, that would be a huge security hole.